# 400 Bad Request Response from long URI in GET HttpWebRequest (>2048 bytes)

Tags: json, httpwebrequest, uri, bad-request, webget

After receiving 404 Not Found errors when trying to send more than 2048 bytes of data, I found [this page](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits) and changed the RequestLimits in IIS to allow more than 2048 (currently set to 8192 to try it out). IIS subsequently added the maxURL and maxQueryString parameters to the Web.config of the API.

Now on those same requests, I'm getting 400 Bad Request, and I can't figure out why. All other requests are still functioning as normal. The functions can now be found with the longer query string, but still can't be processed for some reason.

I'm connecting to an API that was written with WebGets a long time ago. I can't find anything in the Web.config that is restricting the length, or why the a bad request is being returned.

When I use the URL in a browser directly, I receive an "Server Error in '/SDK' Application", so it's not my code calling the WebResponse that is the problem. When I drop some of the content from the middle of the string to below 2048 (as not to malform the structure of the query string), it processes fine.

Does anyone have any suggestions of why this may be occurring, and any potential solutions?